# How to install a "fix released" package for a bug

Tags: dpkg, backport

So, it seems that on my ubuntu <strike>12.04</strike> 11.04 I'm affected by [Bug #971876](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876).

Luckily enough, the bug is marked as "fix released" and a last comment by the Launchpad Janitor says that "This bug was fixed in the package udisks - 1.0.4-5ubuntu2".

How do I install the version 1.0.4-5ubuntu2 in order to solve the problem? I have tried heading to [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/udisks), then downloading the .deb and trying to install it manually. Unfortunately I have an unmet dependency on the version of libc6.

What is the cleanest way to install it on my <strike>12.04</strike> 11.04? Is this what a backport would be for? How can I find it or make it?

I am a bit afraid of manually overriding the version of libc6 and installing a newer one, I wouldn't want to end up breaking the system.

UPDATE: my mistake: the computer I am talking about is not running 12.04 but 11.04.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies . Or try updating as Web-E mentioned. Since the Fix is for Newer release , i don't know if installing that will help. Last option would be compiling or Upgrading to 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

udisks v1.0.4-5ubuntu2 is only available for Ubuntu 12.04

However the only change un udev seems to be the new rule for the card reader. You can it it manually as described in the bug report:

```
echo 'DRIVERS=="rts_bpp", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLASH_SD}="1"' | sudo tee -a /lib/udev/rules.d/81-udisks-realtek.rules
```

Of course this is only useful if you have the driver installed:

```
wget http://planet76.com/drivers/realtek/rts-bpp-dkms_1.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dpkg -i rts-bpp-dkms_1.1_all.deb
```

I don't know if this driver works with Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. (or update via `update manager`).

This will download the new package.

For solving unmet dependency you can run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Sorry, my fault: the ubuntu version is 11.04, not 12.04. I suppose this changes your answer...

Comment: But the bug you pointed is reported in 12.04? Are you sure you were hit by same bug?